# Folding YAML keys hierarchy

Tags: yaml

I am wondering if it is possible to fold YAML keys into single line.

Like to transform:

```yaml
lvl1:
  lvl2:
    lvl3:
      lvl4:
        key1: val1
        key2: val2
```

into something like:

```yaml
lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4:
  key1: val1
  key2: val2
```

I see such syntax in Java Spring Framework config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can write this as it's valid YAML. However it will make `lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4` a single key. If you want to write your YAML like this, you'll need to implement post-loading logic to transform it into the original structure.

In Spring, dotting the levels together works [because](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml)

> The YamlPropertiesFactoryBean will load YAML as Properties

Properties in Java are a list of key-value pairs, so nested mappings are transformed into a list of keys where each key incorporates its path from the document root. Your transformed YAML would look like this:

```
lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4.key1=val1
lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4.key2=val2
```

This result is identical for both your original and the condensed YAML file, which is why you can do this in Spring config files. However, it is not a feature of YAML itself.

---

A format that uses condensed dotted notation is [TOML](https://toml.io/en/):

```
[lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.lvl4]
key1 = "val1"
key2 = "val2"
```

Above document yields the same structure as your original YAML file.