# Automatically format YAML to use dot separator where possible

Tags: yaml, intellij-plugin, tooling

I am using IntelliJ and want to find a quick way to format a lot of yaml files from this:

```yaml
something:
  some:
    thing:
      enable: true
a:
  b:
    c: true
    d:
      e: false
```

to this:

```yaml
something.some.thing.enable: true
a.b:
  c: true
  d.e: false
```

whereever possible. It is still valid syntax, but in the files in question, it is way better to read and often times, elements really just contain one value.

Is there an offline tool, plugin or maven/gradle build step I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> It is still valid syntax

Yes, but it doesn't do what you think it does. `d.e` in YAML will simply load as string `"d.e"`. There is no YAML logic that splits at the dot like you seem to assume.

Java Spring does some postprocessing that causes this to be loaded properly, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64221277/347964). However, this does not work generally with YAML.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303779/347964) for a `yq` command that does something like this – however it will print a full path for each value and you probably don't want that. Doing what you want is probably too complex for `yq`, but not impossible to achieve.

Also mind that queries about finding external tools are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I did not know it was a java (or in my case spring) thing to fix the paths up. Where would such a question be on topic?

Comment: @TreffnonX [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), though I wouldn't bet on an oven-ready solution existing precisely because this is Spring- *and* YAML-specific.